# How to add several views into one tab group in workbench perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How to make two views to occupy entire space and be able to switch by tabs?

My code is like this:

```
package org.eclipsercp.hyperbola;

import org.eclipse.ui.IPageLayout;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleConstants;

public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {


        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.addView(ContactsView.ID, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.5f, layout.getEditorArea());
        //layout.addStandaloneView(ContactsView.ID, false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 1.0f, layout.getEditorArea());

        layout.addView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.5f, layout.getEditorArea());
    }
}
```

I can split area into sections but cant push two views into same place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IFolderLayout` for this purpose:

```
public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

    public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    IFolderLayout folder = layout.createFolder("Folder", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.5f, layout.getEditorArea());
    folder.addView(ContactsView.ID);
    folder.addView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
    }
}
```